# Probability of a picking a white ball in second draw

Tags: probability

Qn:Two balls are selected sequentially from an urn containing six red, three white, and four blue balls. What is the probability of selecting a white ball on the second draw if
the first ball is not replaced before the second is selected?

My attempt:

The first ball can be white or non-white(red or blue).

case 1:The first ball is white:
Then the probability of second ball is white is $3/13*2/12 = 1/26$.

case 2:The first ball is non-white:
Then the probability of second ball is white is $10/13*3/12 = 5/26$.

So the total probability is $ 1/26 + 5/26 = 3/13$.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

A more rigorous way of writing it would be using conditioning.

Let $W_i$ be the random variable corresponding to drawing of white balls.

$$W_i=\begin{cases}1\text{ If ball i is white}\\0\text{ Otherwise}\end{cases}$$

\begin{align}
P(W_2=1)&=\sum_xP(W_2=1\;|\;W_1=x)\times P(W_1=x)\\
&=P(W_2=1\;|\;W_1=0)\times P(W_1=0)+P(W_2=1\;|\;W_1=1)\times P(W_1=1)\\
&=\dfrac{10}{13}\times \dfrac{3}{12}+\dfrac{3}{13}\times \dfrac{2}{12}\\
&=\dfrac{3}{13}\\
&\blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: Why you added these probabilities because these are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @Vinod. Implicitly, yes. I used the law of total probability. So, I condition on disjoint events and sum up the conditional probabilities. As you may have noticed in many problems, conditioning on something useful makes the problem really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is indeed a correct answer